# Does a ConcurrentSkipListMap sort on a key modification? (As well as other auto sorting structures)

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, dictionary

Suppose I have a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and I construct it by giving it a comparator and then add several key value pairs to it. When I add a key to the map, by design it sorts the value based on the comparator given to the constructor or it's natural ordering. However, does the list re-sort itself if I modify one of the keys contained in the map?

i.e.
If I had a map that sorted on first names and I added `"Alan"` and `"Grace"` it would look like so:

```
[0] "Alan"
[1] "Grace"
```

If I then changed `"Alan"` -> `"Turing"` would the list look like

example A:

```
[0] "Turing"
[1] "Grace"
```

Or example B:

```
[0] "Grace"
[1] "Turing"
```

Is this documented behavior for any other auto sorting data structures?

Comment: How would you modify the key? By removing the old and then putting in the new? if this is the case YES.

Comment: How do you define "change the key"?

Comment: suppose your keys were objects, if you were to iterate through the keyset you can modify a field within one of those objects.

Comment: Your title states Sorting on Value Modification. That doesn't happen. All depends on the Order of the Keys. So Key[0] with "Alan" still becomes the first entry Key[0] with "Turing"

Comment: I used the wrong terminology in my title, I've fixed it

Comment: How does the map should keep track of object intern changes? Via reflection, or rendering data encapsulation useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that doesn't change the order:

```
public class TestMap implements Comparable<TestMap> {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private int count;

    public TestMap() {
        count = counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return count + "";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestMap o) {
        return count - o.count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConcurrentSkipListMap<TestMap, String> x = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        TestMap a = new TestMap();
        TestMap b = new TestMap();
        x.put(a, "A");
        x.put(b, "B");
        System.out.println("Before");
        for (Map.Entry<TestMap, String> entry : x.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " val: " + entry.getValue());
        }

        for (TestMap t : x.keySet()) {
            if (t.count == 0) {
                t.count = 5;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After");
        for (Map.Entry<TestMap, String> entry : x.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " val: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before
Key: 0 val: A
Key: 1 val: B
After
Key: 5 val: A
Key: 1 val: B
```